# How do I fix that my website doesn't see my hyperlink

Tags: html, css

(ignore the fact that items in the header are in different language) Hyperlink of header's items doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it. When I put a cursor on a div my cursor doesn't change to a hand. It looks like website doesn't see my div? Or something like that? I've no idea. I send HTML/CSS code.

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 1700px;
}

#header {
  width: 800px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}

#photo {
  height: 980px;
  width: 1864px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(domek.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 15px 0px grey;
}

#oferta {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

#rezerwacja {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

#atrakcje {
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

#kontakt {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

#galeria {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo" style="position:relative;"></div>

<div id="header" style="position:absolute;">
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>

  <div id="oferta" style="color: white;"><a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank" style="color:white;">Oferta</a></div>
  <div id="kontakt">Kontakt</div>
  <div id="rezerwacja">Rezerwacja</div>
  <div id="atrakcje">Atrakcje</div>
  <div id="galeria">Galeria</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You `body` has `height` of `0`. Floating elements and elements with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` do not contribute to the height of the parent element.

Comment: Protip: Don't use floats for anything other than wrapping text around images. For all other cases there are better ways. Also avoid absolute positioning unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Please revise the demo in your post so it shows the problem. Obviously that means not making the text white.

Comment: *unless you have a good reason* **and you know exactly how positioning works in CSS, in detail.** `position` and `float` are definitely only for very advanced CSS users.